# Cannot decode binary string as Unicode ellipsis

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I am reading (in binary) a file and the program halts when it hits `b'\xe2\x80\xa6'`.

```
'''UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2026'
   in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
'''
print(b'\xe2\x80\xa6'.decode('utf-8')) # HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS (U+2026)
```

Comment: I am using Windows, so the key here was to run the "Change Code Page" command: `chcp 65001` before running my script.

Comment: Why are you reading the file as binary when it is encoded as UTF-8?  Use `open(filename,encoding='utf8')` instead.  If using Python 3.6+, it will print fine in the console because that version and later directly write Unicode to the Windows terminal instead of encoding through legacy code pages.

Comment: I am reading a Blizzard `.stl` file, which is a database file containing Strings.